# How can I make data uploaded to a shiny app usable and then actually use it?

Tags: r, date, shiny, coerce

I'm trying to build a shiny app and I've never done this before.

What I want to do is allow the user to upload data from a CSV file of the user's choice that looks something like this:

```
ID    Date        Name        Amount
123   01/12/2018  John Doe    100
124   01/02/2018  Bob Smith   110
125   01/03/2018  Jane Jones  100
126   01/02/2018  John Doe    110
127   01/03/2018  Bob Smith   100
128   01/04/2018  Jane Jones  110
129   01/03/2018  John Doe    100
130   01/04/2018  Bob Smith   110
131   01/04/2018  Jane Jones  120
132   01/14/2018  Tom Thomas  100
```

Then I want to have the app USE this data to run code such as this:

```
as.Date(myDF$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")
sortedByDate = myDF[order(myDF$Date)]
amountPerDate = aggregate(data=myDF, Amount ~ Date, sum)
amountPerDate
```

to produce output such as this:

```
Date        Amount
01/02/2018  220
01/03/2018  300
01/04/2018  340
01/12/2018  100
01/14/2018  100
```

so the user can see the total amount per date, with the dates in correct order. I've been doing stuff like this in regular R script for months but have never before tried it in shiny.

So to upload the data into shiny I'm using this code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
 output$contents <- renderTable({
  inFile <- input$file1
  if(is.null(inFile))
   return(NULL)
  userData = read.csv(inFile$datapath, sep=",")

  #here I run chunks of code to clean the data

  #assign data frame to global environment
  assign("userData", userData, envir = .GlobalEnv)

  #display data table in app
  userData
})
```

So now the user can look at the data but can't DO anything with it.

The data frame in the global environment has every variable as class Factor. I thought it would be easy to coerce the variables into their proper classes (Numeric for "ID" and "Amount", Character for "Name" and Date for "Date" but I can't do it. The very next thing I try to make the app do is display the date in the first row. I tried it with this code:

```
output$text <- renderText({
 userData$Date  = as.Date(as.character(userData$Date), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
 userData[1,2]
})
```

But the output in the app is 17533, NOT 01/12/2018 like I expected.

For some weird reason the following code WILL produce an output of 01/12/2018:

```
output$text <- renderText({
 userData$Date = as.character(userData$Date)
 userData[1,2]
})
```

but I need the dates to be class DATE, not class character.

Without the ability to coerce the variables into their proper classes my entire app is useless. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use assign in Shiny, that is bad practice and it also doesn't allow for any reactivity. Instead, use a reactive to store your input data.

Regarding the unexpected printing output, this probably has to do with the way dates are stored. If you output a Date object in renderText, it will apparently parse it to it's integer value and convert that to character. To prevent that, parse it to character yourself first.

Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    df <- fread(infile$datapath)
    return(df)
  })

  output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(filedata()))
    {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else
    {
      myDF <- filedata() # read the uploaded data from reactive
      myDF$Date <- as.Date(myDF$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y") # Change format!
      sortedByDate = myDF[order(myDF$Date)]
      amountPerDate = aggregate(data=myDF, Amount ~ Date, sum)
      print('done')
      return(amountPerDate)
    }
  })

  output$my_text <- renderText({
    if(is.null(filedata()))
    {
      return(NULL)
    }
    else
    {
      as.character(as.Date(filedata()$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y"))[1]
    }
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv")
  ),
  dataTableOutput('my_table'),
  textOutput('my_text')
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope this helps!